# Visual Studio 2008 with Source Safe: Recover data lost by auto-checkout?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

I am using Visual Source Safe 2005 and Visual Studio 2008.

@#$% this Source Safe.  With programs like Source Safe that @#$% up my data, who needs viruses, hard drive failure, and other assorted calamities.

My story starts with getting my workstation re-imaged on Monday this week.  After the machine was re-imaged, I downloaded from Source Safe the source code I was working on.  Thursday afternoon, I noticed that as I was working on my source code, the files were *not* being automatically checked out from Source Safe as I worked, however there was no problem saving my work on the disk.

So... I needed to check in my work.  I noticed that the files (not checked out from Source Safe) were not read-only as they usually are, so I made them read-only.

I feel like I should have backed up my data locally at this point and I'm now kicking myself for not doing so, but the next thing that I did was I went back to Visual Studio to continue my work and see if I could get the program to automatically check out the files I was changing.

The first time that I began to edit a file (BigLongCodeFile.cs), it automatically checked out the file for me as I had hoped.  However, in a split second it displayed a dialog that explained, *"Your action caused a check out of file(s) BigLongCodeFile.cs, and a new version from source control has been loaded in the develpment environment.  Please re-do your changes if necessary."*  And just like that, Visual Studio undid all the changes I had done to that file since Monday, representing hours of lost work for me.

It didn't prompt if I wanted to do this, just showed me a dialog informing me that the damage is done.  With development tools like this, who needs a virus to destroy his work?

Is there some way to get my data back, or some way to avoid this?

Comment: I should add this during the time this happened, no one else was working on any of the files in Source Control

Comment: I found a discussion by another developer having the same issue.  However, he does not have any solution for how to recover lost data. http://forums.asp.net/t/1004500.aspx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was setting the flag back to read only, which was exacerbated by not making a copy of the files when you found things were not getting auto checked out from SourceSafe. Unless the new copy was written to a different location on the drive, which is unlikely, you are currently hosed. If it could possibly be saved elsewhere (note I am talking physically saved, not logically saved (ie, what you see in Windows Explorer == logical)) you can use an undelete utility. It is a long shot, but you can try undelete tools; I would not hold out much hope.

One of the first things to do when you find source control is not working correctly, and you have altered files, is to make a backup of the folders you have worked on. A simple copy of the structure to a temp location is good enough. Then fix the source control issue and be prepared to consolidate your efforts. There are tools for this, if you are worried someone else might have edited files.

As for why VS did not warn you? The file was flagged as if it was not changed. VS noticed something after the save operation (size change, most likely) and warned you something was in error.

In the past, I have been burned by trying to second guess software, so I know the pain. That is why copy backup is a good practice when you notice something strange. This is less problematic in TFS, but I would imagine it might just overwrite a file that appeared to be checked in (read only flag set) as well.